# How do I wait for a method to finish before calling it again?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am building a simple messaging app using Parse's framework. I have a method called `displayMessages`. This is called each time the phone receives a push.

However, as this message is doing work in the Parse database I don't want to call it again if it's already running. I want to wait until it is finished and then call it.

I am using the following code:

```
-(void)receivedPush
{

    [self displayMessages];

}
```

and:

```
-(void)displayMessages
{
 //code here
}
```

If received push is called I want it to wait until `displayMessages` is finished before calling it. Could someone please point me in the right direction with this?

UPDATE

I tried using the `NSOperationQueue` method and realised that although this does work for waiting for `displayMessages` it doesn't result in the required behavior.

In `displayMessages` I have: `[PFObject deleteAllInBackground:toDelete];` it's actually this I need to wait for completion before calling `displayMessages` again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `NSOperationQueue` and set the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to 1.  Implement your data access method as an operation (possibly block-type operation) and submit it to the queue.  (I like this better than gcd since you can do cancellation or test the number of items already in the queue.)

Note that if the method actually displays things, you'll need to dispatch back to the main queue for UI work.

Comment: hey I am working on the NSOperation queue now. It does work but I realised it won't help give me the functionality I want. I am waiting for displayMessages to finish because there is a Parse call : [PFObject deleteAllInBackground: toDelete]. It's actually that I need to wait for. So a bit stuck now..

Comment: @Kex  I don't know what 'manual' means in this context.  How would you like it to behave?

Comment: I would like the queue to pause anything until I tell it to continue.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `NSOperationQueue` with `maxConcurrentOperationCount` set to `1`.

Declare the `NSOperationQueue` as an iVar of your class, initialize it in the `init` method and set

```
[_opQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
```

and then when you receive the push:

```
- (void)receivedPush {
    NSInvocationOperation *op = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(displayMessages) object:nil];
    [_opQueue addOperation:op];
}
```

Comment: I was trying to figure out NSOperation queue just now actually, will give it a try. thanks

Comment: do I need to redefine my method though as a NSOperation? In a separate class file?

Answer (score 0):

Shortest and simples would be creating BOOL isExecuting and checking if you can call method based on that (changing values before execution but after check and after execution)

Comment: how would I get receivedPush to wait until isExecuting is NO?  a while loop?

Comment: if(!isExecuting){
 isExecuting=YES;
 [self execute];
}

-(void)execute{
...;
isExecuting=NO;
}

Answer (score 0):

How about this for a fairly lightweight solution:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL needsToDisplayMessages;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL displayingMessages;
```

Then

```
-(void)receivedPush
{
    if (!self.displayingMessages) {
        [self displayMessages];
    } else {
        self.needsToDisplayMessages = YES;
   }
}


-(void)displayMessages
 {
  self.needsToDisplayMessages = NO;
  self.displayingMessages = YES;
  //long-running code here

  self.displayingMessages = NO;
  if (self.needsToDisplayMessages) {
       [self displayMessages]
  }
```

(ignoring concurrency issues ... for which you could use GCD in `displayMessages` or `NSOperationQueue` as per a couple of the other answers)

Answer (score 0):

With your new updated requirement, you can use `deleteAllInBackground:block:`.  According to [document](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/deleteAllInBackground:):

"Deletes a collection of objects all at once asynchronously and executes the block when done."

Comment: I have to wait for that to finish deleting though,  right now displayMessages will finish executing while deleteAllInBackground is still in progress

Comment: I would just use a flag and twist with some logic in the completion block of deleteAllInBackground to trigger another displayMessages again.

Answer (score -1):

Why not schedule each message handling using:

```
-(void)receivedPush
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    /* Show the update on the display */
    NSLog(@"Handling new messages");
    NSArray *newMessages=<populate with new messages>;
    [handler displayMessages:newMessages];            
  });
}
```

This will queue up your handling of each set as they come in. Only one displayMessages will run at a time.

Comment: That's a terrible idea because: 1. You're asking GCD to dispatch a block from the main queue to the main queue synchronously... basically you're doing nothing, removing the GCD code will do exactly the same. 2. From the doc "Calling this function and targeting the current queue results in deadlock".

Comment: Should have been shed_async which does place it in the queue. I would have preferred a "did you mean async" rather than a -1.